# How to remove the date from the URL of a post in a specific category, without plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, categories

I need some help to find the solution to remove the url date only from posts in a specific category.

I have my permalinks settings like this:

```
 /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%category%/%postname%/
```

A category-x post has the following url:

> http://mysite/2021/08/25/category-x/post-name/

I need only for category-x posts, the url looks like this:

> http://mysite/category-x/post-name/

The other posts would remain with the date in the url.

I tried to do something with the rewrite_rules_array and post_link filters, with no success.

How could I solve it?

Comment: Maybe the WordPress stack would be a better fit for this question? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', function( $permalink, $post, $leavename ){
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);    
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->slug == "category-x" ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/category-x/'. $post->post_name . '/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}, 10, 3 ); 

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules',function( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $new_rules['^category-x/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
});
```

Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Changing category base prefix
[image]

Try Redirects After Changing Category Base Prefix

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it's not exactly what I need. All posts must keep the url structure with the date, except for "category-x" posts.